# Packages for arithmetic with algebraic numbers in C++?

Tags: math, numbers

I am looking for a C++-compatible package that can do arithmetic with algebraic numbers. (Note: an algebraic number means a number that is a root of a polynomial with integer coefficients, so it is not given as a decimal or rational expression).

Mathematica handles algebraic numbers as "root objects", which are represented by polynomials with a choice of root. Then two such root objects can be added, multiplied, etc, and then reduced, to get a new root object.

Is there some software that does the same thing in C++? I have seen some fancy number theory packages that do various things with number field extensions, but I would prefer something simple than can just do basic arithmetic with algebraic numbers, i.e. addition, subtraction, multipication, division, reducing, testing for equality. .

Answer (score 1):

[Givaro](http://ljk.imag.fr/CASYS/LOGICIELS/givaro/): C++ library for arithmetic and algebraic computations

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica has a way of interfacing with C++. If this could work for you, I would recommend this method, as your needs may be too localized to find a package which already has everything you need and not much else.

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/CLanguageInterface.html

Comment: Thanks, interfacing with Mathematica may indeed be the best approach. I'm a bit worried about the speed, if the program has to call Mathematica for every algebraic operation, but maybe it won't be too bad.

Comment: If you check out the page I linked, then you'll notice that you can export a Mathematica function to C source code. You can then place this code in your project. Thus, this won't be calling external executables and will not have that overhead.